# How to install Wordpress on subdirectory of my domain using Aamazon Web Server

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, installation, server

> Hi, I am trying to install a WordPress in a subdirectory
>   "domain.com/wordpres". But I don't know anything about Amazon Web
>   Server. I tried youtube and google. but they only show that how to
>   install WordPress on AWS. nothing more in deep detail.

**Please help me, if anyone knows how to install WordPress on a subdirectory of my domain on the AWS server, or suggest me any proper post/tutorial.**

Thanks.

Comment: Install wordpress normally you do and once installed move it to sub directory from root.

Comment: **Kush Vyas** already have an installation on the root directory. someone else did before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like say the guys, you need install wordpress normally.

First your need connect with your instance, this is a virtual server, the ssh protocol is commonly used.
I recommend read the documentation.

For linux instance: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstances.html

For Windows instance: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/connecting_to_windows_instance.html

Second step is install your web server normally, LAMP or WAMP depending your instance, i recommend apache, mysql or MariaDB and the last version of php, but exist a lot web servers softwares for your choice. If you have not a experiencie read this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

Finally your need download the need version of wordpress, edit config file (wp-config.php) and run.
If you have not a experiencie read this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html

Note: If you need "domain.com/wordpress" is possible with VirtualHost in apache.
Documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html